# How to format static variable declarations with R#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, LocalizationLanguage> _languages = new Dictionary<int, LocalizationLanguage>() {
    {0,new LocalizationLanguage { CultureInfo = "en-US", Id = 0 }},
{1,new LocalizationLanguage { CultureInfo = "es-AR", Id = 1 }}
    };
```

I have this declaration, and it doesn't autowrap into something nice, whereas if I do the exact same but with a property accessor, it formats perfectly to:

```
    private static Dictionary<int, LocalizationLanguage> _languages
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dictionary<int, LocalizationLanguage>()
               {
                   {0, new LocalizationLanguage {CultureInfo = "en-US", Id = 0}},
                   {1, new LocalizationLanguage {CultureInfo = "es-AR", Id = 1}}
               };
        }
    }
```

What's the reason for this and how can I make either vs2010 or R# auto-format this kind of expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested this myself, as I use vs2010 and R# myself. It automatically reformats the code to:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<int, LocalizationLanguage> _languages =
    new Dictionary<int, LocalizationLanguage>()
        {
            { 0, new LocalizationLanguage { CultureInfo = "en-US", Id = 0 } },
            { 1, new LocalizationLanguage { CultureInfo = "es-AR", Id = 1 } }
        };
```

vs2010 reformats the code upon completion of the statement (entering the `;`). I tested by pasting your unformatted code into visual studio, and erasing the final `};`. Typing it again automatically formats it. I also tested having different variations of the original code before closing the statement and it formats it the same no matter what.

I would guess there is an issue with your vs2010 or R# in this case?